# "Complete" confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, terminology, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

The word "complete" seems to be used in several distinct ways. Perhaps my confusion is as much linguistic as mathematical?

1. A basis, by definition, spans the space; some books call this "complete" -- though then the phrase "complete basis" is redundant.
2. In physics/engineering, "complete" seems to be reserved for orthogonal/orthonormal bases -- which necessarily means not merely a vector space, but specifically an inner product space.  A complete basis in this QM sense does more than merely span the space: the concept of orthogonality allows for Parseval's relation, non-overlapping projections, Gram-Schmidt, etc.  Is it even possible to have a complete basis (in this QM sense) that is NOT orthogonal?
3. Though [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) in the sense of Hilbert space and Cauchy sequences seems to be a different use of the term, the convergence of sequences within the space seems not so far afield, conceptually, from Parseval.  So is it really so different?

Comment: Yes, there are non-equivalent uses of the word "complete". We have to live with that.

Comment: 2.) is not true, in my opinion. We are using "complete" in exactly the same sense as mathematicians. One of the first things they taught us in my first math classes for physicists was indeed Gram-Schmidt diagonalization. It can't be any other way because many physics problems do not come with orthogonal/orthonormal bases built in and in many systems (crystal lattices) they wouldn't even be a good natural choice. Moreover, as a physicist I am constantly aware that the existence of inner products and in case of Hilbert spaces completeness for infinite series of elements are a special property.

Comment: Yes, inner products abound in physics. But this is additional structure not required of vector spaces or their bases.

Comment: Let me put it this way: what's the completeness relation for a non-orthogonal basis?

Comment: Related question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98462/use-of-complete-as-in-complete-set-of-states-or-complete-basis

Answer (score 4):

As noted, many people use "complete" where perhaps they ought to say "complete and orthogonal and orthonormal" or the like. I'm not sure what I can tell you besides confirming that usage is not always ideal. I'll answer one question you brought up, but I'm worried I may have gotten confused myself by what kind of "complete" you meant:

> Is it even possible to have a complete basis (in this QM sense) that is NOT orthogonal?

Yep! Consider, for instance, the [coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states). They're not orthogonal, since $\langle \alpha | \beta \rangle$ isn't zero for $\alpha \neq \beta$. But they are complete--indeed, "overcomplete."

Comment: By complete in the "QM sense" I mean the sum/integral over ket-bra being unity.

Comment: Ah. The integral over all the coherent states is $\pi I$. I'll think about your actual question, then, maybe I'll come up with a weird degenerate case (or a counterproof).

Comment: Could you not just add a factor of 1/sqrt(pi) to one of the states? the states would then be complete, and still not orthogonal?

Comment: They would be complete -- but then they'd be neither orthogonal nor normalized!

Comment: An overcomplete set is a spanning set.  But it still seems to me that (over)complete in the QM sense requires an inner product space

Comment: @gilonik The word complete does require a metric (so an inner product would do). When you say something is overcomplete you mean that you can remove things from it and have it still be complete. The same things happen with spanning sets, you might want to add more vectors to get a frame that is spanning and then some maybe for redundancy. Sometimes you like redundancy, sometimes you like unique linear combinations sometimes you like unique finite linear combinations. Set up your system to give you want you want, I'm trying to make you aware of the options not fight about terminology.

Comment: My apologies if I sounded combative -- I'm trying to understand the terminology, not fight over it!  But I think you (and yuugib) hit the key distinction:  completeness is a metric space concept, and so is not as "primitive" as a basis or spanning set.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful with the word span. A mathematician will say that the span of a set of vectors is the set of finite linear combinations, so you can only add linear combinations of finitely many at a time to get something in the span.  So there are sets that are mutually orthogonal and all normalized but not enough to span the space with finite linear combinations.  But we call them complete if the span is large enough so that its completion (by filling in any holes) is the whole space. So in a sense we call an orthonormal set of vectors complete if the infinite linear combinations make up the whole space.

But for infinite linear combinations we need a metric, like that from an inner product. So the whole notion doesn't make sense in an arbitrary vector space but can make sense in a Hilbert Space. In a Hilbert Space not only is there an inner product (and hence a metric) so that we cab talk about the limit, but Cauchy sequences have things to converge to, so there is something to be the limit of your sum.

So when you say complete for an orthonormal basis you are talking about infinite sums. And saying that the sun if the projections is the identity is usually how you express it, but that requires limits of operators not just vectors, so technically you then need to put a metric on your space of operators if you want to characterize it that way, so then completeness of an orthonormal basis now depends on how you define distances and take limits of operators. But you do need to define that if you want to talk about the exponential of an operator.

And as long as we've brought up completeness and operators. I should warn you that when a mathematician says state, as in quantum state, they might mean an operator such as a density operator.

Now this is a matter of terminology, but the word complete is usually reserved as a matter of definition to orthonormal seta of vectors. And as a definition there is nothing deep about it.

If you always think of complete as enough then you are fine. When you have a set of orthonormal vectors so large that you can't add another orthonormal vector then it is complete. When you've filled in so many holes that every Cauchy sequence now has something to converge to then your space is complete.

But that complete set of orthonormal vectors is not as big as it can be if you give up on being orthonormal. As a set if linearly independent vectors there are potentially more vectors that could be added to the set that can't be written as finite linear combinations of the vectors already there. So they are not enough in an algebraic sense it is only in the metric sense that they are enough. And that's morally why you insist on orthogonality, it is only when you insisted on orthogonality that you had a sense where you couldn't add more.

Oh, and a basis is supposed to just barely span, so not have too many. The coherent states from another answer are overcomplete and have too many vectors.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  Are you saying, e.g., that a spin j basis spans but is not complete?  That may be good mathematical terminology, but the distinction is not sufficiently consequential to be made in QM.

Comment: @gilonik I'm not sure I'm following you. In a finite dimensional space you don't have to worry about completeness because your inner product space is already complete and your orthonormal basis is already complete. A finite dimensional inner product space is always a Hilbert space but an infinite dimensional ip space might not be and so you need to bring up completeness. I'm saying that span means finite linear combination, and therefore your #1 is technically not true: a complete basis might not technically be a basis because it might not technically span the space. It's confusing terminology

Answer (score 1):

Completeness in mathematics is essentially a metric concept (that means that every Cauchy sequence in the metric space converges to an element of the space).

Sometimes (but I think more on a physical standpoint, and I agree is a sort of repetition and not so common) it is used to characterize bases in vector spaces, in the sense that a basis is complete if its linear span is the whole vector space. The axiom of choice implies that every vector space has a basis.

The orthonormal basis on a Hilbert space is actually different: the space has such additional structure that we can afford to do infinite linear combinations of vectors, provided they converge in norm. However, be warned that a (complete) basis of orthogonal vectors in a vector space with inner product $V$ (in the finite linear combination sense), it is not in general a (complete) basis of the metric (Hilbert) space obtained as the completion of $V$ with respect to the metric induced by the inner product. However it may happen that it is a basis in the Hilbert space sense, i.e. if infinite linear combinations are allowed.

Apart from that and mathematical logic, that is probably quite far from what it is intended here, I cannot think of other instances of the word complete in math (but maybe I am forgetting something).

However, since in one case "complete" is associated to a (metric) space, and in the other to bases in vector spaces (possibly with additional care to specify if we allow finite or infinite combinations), I think it reasonably easy to avoid confusion.

Comment: Saying complete means the span is the space is wrong, a basis already spans and when we say complete basis it technically doesn't span. A basis is either a minimal spanning set or a maximal linearly independent set. It always spans the set. However when we call something an orthogonal basis we don't mean a basis that happens to be orthogonal we instead mean a maximal orthogonal linearly independent set, which can then end up not being a spanning set at all and instead spans something dense, spans something whose completion is the space. So we mean the completion of the span is the space.

Comment: @Timaeus Every vector space has a basis (it is a proved theorem) that, as per definition, spans the space. This basis is "complete" (I said it was not so good and redundant terminology). And given a vector space $V$ with inner product structure, even if there is an orthogonal basis (there may be or not) that spans the whole space (surely there is at least a basis that spans the whole space, and maybe is of pairwise orthogonal vectors) then it would be not, in general, a basis of the metric space obtained as a completion of the inner product vector space. I stand by the fact that it is correct

Comment: I agree, however, that the concept of orthogonal bases in Hilbert spaces is different, for it allows for infinite linear combinations, provided they converge in norm. That is, however, another definition of basis that is usual of Hilbert and Banach spaces (Schauder basis). I also agree that complete in that sense is not a so good terminology, however it is completely unrelated to the one that refers to complete metric spaces.

Comment: @Timaeus As an addition, I remark that a basis on the vector space sense (finite combinations) of a separable Hilbert space indeed exists, but it may be (and probably is) uncountable. On the  contrary, the basis in the Schauder sense, i.e. with infinite linear combinations is countable.

Comment: You say it is a theorem that every vector space has a basis but it is not a theorem in any useful definition of the word. It is a baseless assumption. ZF plus C and certain methods of deduction produce "every vector space has a basis" as a theorem, but on the other hand ZF plus  "every vector space has a basis" and the exact same methods of deduction yield C as a theorem. So the so called theorem is equivalent to an axiom that has no basis. I think Hamel bases are unrelated to Physics for that exact reason.

Comment: As for your claim that Schauder bases are unrelated metric completeness you are definitely wrong in the only case that matters, the unique separable Hilbert space where the metric closure of the span of a maximal orthogonal set is indeed the whole Hilbert space. In a finite dimensional vector spaces you don't need the word complete and there us just one separable Hilbert space and how can you use a non separable Hilbert space to do science?

Comment: @Timaeus A theorem is a true statement in a logical theory with inference rules, axioms and schemas. And so in ZFC "every vector space has a basis" is a theorem (in the only mathematical definition of the word). It is true that the full axiom of choice and "every vector has a basis" are equivalent, nevertheless it is not a big deal, we use plenty of theorems that are reformulations of the axiom of choice in physics. In addition, with weaker forms of choice you may still prove that many vector spaces have bases.

Comment: @Timaeus And I have not said that Schauder bases are unrelated to completeness of the space,I just said that the notion of "complete basis",intended as a basis that either "finitely spans" or "infinitely spans" a space is unrelated with the notion of completeness of a metric space.And finally, non-separable spaces important in physics:an example of a relevant Banach non-separable space is the algebra of operators that satisfy the canonical commutation relations. In addition, there are some conjectures that non-separable Hilbert spaces may be interesting in QFT (but surely are just hypotheses).

Comment: A logic theory to be meaningful is always assumed to be consistent. And you should really take a good basic book on the foundations of mathematics and look at how a theorem is defined (I suggest you the Set theory book of Bourbaki).

Comment: With your point of view, Zorn's lemma, Zermelo well-ordering theorem, Hahn-Banach theorem (it is equivalent to a slightly weaker form of choice), the ultrafilter lemma...(I can go on and on) are all not theorems, but dishonest statements.

Comment: No a theorem is not a true statement in an axiom system, for instance your axiom system could be inconsistent (and ZFC indeed could be inconsistent) in which case if you use the (currently) most popular deductive method then all statements in the language are theorem. A and nota aren't both true. A theorem is a actually just a statement that is generated via a particular method. In your case you tried to say something was a theorem in a totally dishonest way because you knew that ZF+C is equivalent to ZF+EVSHAB and probably know that consistency of your system is unknown.

Comment: Assuming stuff and calling it a theorem just to make it look like you didn't just assume it is totally dishonest.

Comment: As for assuming your axiom system is consistent, if playing pretend or make believe helps you do things because being honest while also generating theorems at the same time isn't your style, then I respect your personal choice. But to tell someone that something has to be a certain way because you assumed it was is another thing entirely. And to then pretend you weren't doing that. That is a step too far. You don't know if every vector space has a basis. You personally like to assume so and then you wanted to claim your way was the only way. That is a dishonest thing to do, you can do better

Comment: @Timaeus The consistency of ***no*** theory can be proved within the theory itself (Gödel's second incompleteness theorem). Anyways you can prove the consistency of a theory "outside" of the theory, as Gentzen did with arithmetics. There is also a method called forcing to construct new consistent theories starting from models and prove independence of axioms. As I said, a theorem is a perfectly defined mathematical object and fits very well with logic.

Comment: If you want to do mathematics outside of ZFC very well, do it. But remember that you have to prove **everything** by scratch from the axioms you may wish to assume (and that you **cannot prove** to be consistent within the theory, if it contains arithmetics). You use the axiom of choice a lot, I can assure you. Personally, I am very well aware of what I am doing when I say that something is a theorem, and what it does mean, i.e. that it is a true statement in a precise logic theory.

Comment: You probably do not care, because you don't do rigorous mathematics. But to be so pretentious as to say that those who do mathematics are just cheating because they use axiom systems assuming their consistency, that is dishonest.

Comment: Systems can't prove their own consistency from within the system if they also have certain other properties such as containing large enough portions of a popular arithmetic system. Yes your favorite systems have those properties, but again when you falsely pretend that everyone has to do things the way you like to do them that is a step too far. Dan Willard studies consistent systems that prove their own consistency. It is not right to pretend that people have to do things the way you like to do them, and it undermines the credibility of mathematicians when they do that.

Comment: When such theories will provide interesting and powerful results, I will be very happy to use those systems. It is a pity that within these theories you can prove so few results. Anyways, I do not want everyone to do things as I like, simply I do want that if someone gives a mathematical result, does that knowing what it does mean and what he is doing. And ZFC is by immensely far the most common logical system used by mathematicians and physicists, so it is customary to say that something is a theorem omitting "in ZFC" (and you also do that wheneveer in your answers here give a true result)

Comment: Now you're telling me I use the axiom of choice? I make physical predictions which means I have to study ways of making actual predictions by actual methods that produce real results with a finite amount of work. Using the axiom of choice doesn't help me study actual implementable algorithms just like the most popular deductive method doesn't help me study actual implementable algorithms. Both can help me communicate with people that like to use them.  Pretending you can do things that can't actually be done isn't a very useful activity.

Comment: I objected not to the fact that you said EVSHAB but the way you said it, where you made it sound like it wasn't an assumption, like there aren't alternatives. In science we have to be fair to all alternatives, sure some areas might have an advantage because of lots of prior work to build on and that is a legitimate consideration but in science we must be honest we can't unfairly characterize other theories. No real computer contains all of arithmetic so why do we need axiom systems that assume you can compute things you can't really compute with your actual computer.

Comment: You've repeated (as in made the same claim again) your claim that theorems are true. And you did this after I pointed out that your system might be inconsistent and hence by using your favorite (but not required) deductive method generates both $S$ and $\neg S$ as theorems. So maybe the truth you meant is "axioms A imply theorem T" or even more precisely "axioms A and deductive method K generates statement T" which are actual true things, and can be proven with the same tools we use to do science, such as by finite computations. There isn't anything wrong with that.

Comment: And yes, you can say "is theorem" could be a shorthand for that, but it crosses the line to dishonesty if you pretend that wasn't what you are doing. When you pretend that we have to have EVSHAB and therefore can't use, say NF, instead of ZFC. I'm not saying you can't privately assume that your system is consistent as you go about your work. I'm saying that if instead of facing your competition fairly and instead of owning your assumption you pretend that yours was the only option, then you do yourself and your field a disservice

Comment: It's how you said that I objected to, as if there was no alternative to EVSHAB and that I objected to because it is not good science, and this is a Physics site. It isn't good science to be unfair to your competition. If someone makes a prediction and it disagrees with observation, then all cards need to be on the table, the equipment, the calculations, the theories, the ideas, even the math itself. Anything that was used to test the prediction needs to be scrutinized. No one gets a free ride. Sure, some things are first in line and others might be last. But nothing is above the law.

Comment: Now, there is a whole meta level where you assume your axiom system and assume its consistency, which if done privately I respect.  But then present it a different way, as if you have more evidence in your favor and less evidence against it than really exists, that is not OK.  And now you go beyond that and claim that I'm pretentious and repeatedly tell me that I need to read basic books. When I tell you with precision why I disagree with you. That's actually 100% a pure ad hominum fallacy. I've told you that what you are doing is dishonest regarding suppressing evidence against you.

Comment: And when I say you can do better, I mean it. You are capable of not using dishonest tactics because I know you are a good and capable person. I'm not even telling you that anything you do is unproductive in a suitable setting, amongst mathematicians that already know about ZF, NF, ZFC, NFU, NGB, and ZF+V=L and are familiar with Dan Willard's work and Gödel's work and the equivalents of the axiom of choice and classical logic and constructive logic and synthetic differential geometry and dialethism and know the full range of which deductive methods (axioms and deductive methods) are available.

Comment: They know what you mean.  And so do I. But here, in this place of science, it is not right or honest to claim you have more evidence than you actually have.  I am not judging your for what you do privately or elsewhere. I'm saying that here, if your audience here, can't tell the difference between "it must be so" and "it must be so if we assume all the usually things we like to assume and don't want to state all the time because that would be annoying am I right?" then you are doing a completely different thing by saying the exact same words here. And it's not pretentious to tell you that.

Comment: @Timaeus Look, you have a very distorted and acrimonious behavior towards mathematics (and in particular me) that is completely unjustified. You like computable things, it is ok, and there is mathematics done to allow only that (constructivist/finitist program). You don't care about math at all? Also that is fine. But don't say that mathematical results are put in apresumptuous way because it is absolutely false. When we apply mathematics to physics (and there is a whole branch called mathematical physics to do that) we use mathematics as a tool to make predictions.

Comment: And if the prediction is in contradiction with experimental facts, it means that some of the assumptions are not true, for the rigorous structure of mathematics does not introduce errors, approximations as a numerical calculation does. It is perfectly scientific, and does not pretend at all to be an absolute truth, simply a truth within some assumptions, that if experimentally falsified means one or more of the assumptions are false. It is in stark contrast with what you say.

Comment: I will give you a very simple example. In mathematical physics there is a lot of work nowadays to rigorously justify the mean field approximation. This is done proving theorems in a matheematical way, showing that e.g. many non-relativistic bosons with pair potential behave, in the limit when they are many, as dictated by the Hartree/Gross-Pitaevski equations. It also provide quantitative bounds on the error done in the approximation. This is done in a setting where ZFC is necessary from a math point of view.

Comment: If you try to do calculations and make computable predictions, you can predict much much less than with math (for you need a lot of approximations). So the mathematical model is more fit to be tested, and eventually contradicted as it is sciense, directly on the experimental level than numerical computations because it is more "precise" in some sense.

Comment: And if some day you would find an experimental instance in nature that contradicts with ZFC as a basic set theory, I will be happy to shift to another theory to model physical reality. If else, since it works very well and give really accurate predictions I will stay with it, and I don't think this is dishonest at all; just an effective way to produce interesting results.

Comment: What is distorted? I know in detail how theorems are actually generated, from the actual axioms that are used to the actual methods used to generate theorems from axioms. It's not a distortion for me to be aware that a theorem is a statement generated from other statements in a particular manner. But unlike an average physicist I realize that there are many systems you can use. Just as you can use euclidean geometry and non euclidean geometry you can similarly use ZFC or you can use NFU they are different and one isn't an obvious choice over the other.

Comment: I brought up computation to point out that, as scientists, we aren't required to talk about things beyond what we need to to make testable predictions that can be made with finite means. We don't have to stick to that. You just said something is apresumptuous or that it isn't apresumptuous I can't tell what you are referring to. If you use a potentially inconsistent system with a method that generates all possible statements from an inconsistent system then saying "X is a theorem" isn't saying much, we could wait to see if later you say "$\neg$ X is a theorem" what is the point?

Comment: You claim math doesn't introduce error, but if you hide your assumptions and your assumptions can be self inconsistent then to someone that is unaware of the assumptions you used they must treat you like a source of error. Only by having your assumptions available can you be a contributor to science.

Comment: I'm still not sure you've groked anything I've said. Trying to introduce rigor could include rigorously seeing consequences from assumptions but then you need to state your assumptions and are limited by them. Or introducing rigor could be more in the style of reverse mathematics where you try to see what can give you a result you want to see what could generate it. But often rigor is mentioned as if mathematicians know the truth and want to pontificate from a position of authority. That's fine. If. The assumptions are put in the table. Otherwise it is not science.

Comment: As for revising ZFC when indirect proofs are a common theorem generation technique it's not clear you'll recognize an inconsistency if you come across them because you assume axioms and their consistency and X and then get a contradiction and choose to blame X. If there is always an X to blame then it might take a long time if the shortest proof of a contradiction is very long but logically all statements are theorems if there is a contradiction. So saying it is a theorem by itself just means you have a proof. Proofs are useful. Constructive proofs even more so (Howard-Curry).

Comment: I'm actually still surprised that we are arguing. I objected to the way (including context) you chose to express your assertion that EVSHAB was a theorem  when any statement could be a theorem if your system and it is just as fair to say that EVSHAB was logically independent of the axioms that are actually used to describe real computers that do real computations and so you added EVSHAB as an axiom and thus got EVSHAB as a theorem since every axiom is technically a theorem (with a very short proof).

Comment: I very well know the boundaries of mathematical theories, and what it is meant by giving proofs and what are the possible limitations of an axiom system. It seems, however, that you do not grasp very well what is the problem with the second godel incompleteness theorem. The problem **is not** that there may be contradictory statements. Not at all, it is simply that you need a stronger logical theory to prove consistency of a theory. ZFC is proved to be a consistent theory within a theory where a suitable inaccessible cardinal exists.

Comment: Well I guess we might also be still arguing that if you have a maximal orthonormal set in a separable Hilbert space that the completion of the span is Hilbert Space isomorphic to the original Hilbert Space.

Comment: It is a problem of truth complexity, i.e. how many logical "steps" you need to prove the theory. The contradictory statements are excluded as long as your axioms are independent, i.e. each one is unprovable by the others.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, but it isn't a "problem" for me because it merely tells me the cost of putting in structures that I don't always have to use. Having an inaccessible cardinal doesn't help much if ZF is inconsistent and we don't actually know if it is inconsistent

Comment: I am arguing simply that you are very stubborn in not accepting that mathematical theories are meaningful, and axiom systems are constructed in order to get interesting results that are scientific. And not contradictory monsters that makes the mathematicians feel superior. And are you sure you can prove any mathematical statement in your answer here (or in your work) by finitist methods? I very hardly think so...

Comment: And indeed there might be contradictory statements generatable from ZF and that's life. But we can make consistent theories that we know are consistent because we can make theories that accurately describe finite models.

Comment: It isn't hard to make theories that are complete and consistent. And it is possible that one of them can describe our universe accurately. Yay. And it is an open question whether ZF is consistent. And if ZF is inconsistent then neither ZF nor ZFC can describe our universe if our universe is consistent (in a different sense of the word)

Comment: Ah, we might now have a place to focus our disagreement. See I know that ZF+C and ZF+$\neg$C are equiconsistent, but this just means "ZF implies (ZF and C are independent)" it does not mean "ZF and C are independent" because if ZF were already inconsistent then "ZF and C are not independent" because then C is a theorem of the inconsistent ZF. So we don't actually know if ZF is inconsistent because we didn't prove all the axioms to be independent of each other. We don't actually know if the axioms of ZF are independent of each other, if we did then we'd know they are consistent. And we don't.

Comment: Actually ZFC + IC proves the consistency of both ZFC and ZF. So really, the existence of contradictory statements is not worrying. Forcing is actually a very powerful method to prove consistency of new logical model with interesting properties (as the Solovay model that is ZF+DC and all sets of reals are measurable).

Comment: I've only objected to hiding evidence and being unfair to competitors. I don't object to any creation of the human mind that is honest, I mean sure some of them don't agree with observation, but testable theories have to have the possibility to be wrong, so I'm not going to protest that something disagrees with observation, I'll just label at such.

Comment: If ZF is inconsistent then ZF+AnyAxiom implies the consistency of ZF since ZF implies the consistency if ZF. So when you write ZF+AnyAxiom implies the consistency of ZF what we know is that either ZF is inconsistent or ZF is consistent. Something we already knew. Sure, if ZF is consistent then we have to be careful which AnyAxiom to put there since not just anything will work. But if ZF is inconsistent then anything would have worked. So putting something there and getting a theorem that ZF is consistent doesn't convince me or convince anyone.

Comment: No, it really seemed that you were objecting the consistency of mathematics and the validity of it as a science. And in a very unpleasing and stubborn manner to be honest. It seems that you do not like axiomatic theories where there is incompleteness, and that you are not satisfied even if you are shown evidence that there are methods to prove consistency of these theories that in my opinion comply with the intuition that to prove a complex system you need to use method of "additional complexity", i.e. out of the system itself.

Comment: I've actually made many theories myself that meet the exact criteria you just suggested. And yes a few of them I don't like (in the sense that I do not personally enjoy proving theorems in them) but I don't object to them. I just don't see any evidence that ZF is such a theory. I mean it is axiomatic and it is math. I just don't see any evidence of its consistency

Comment: No, here you are profoundly wrong. In those models of $ZFC+something$ you prove that there are no contradictory statements, because you prove that there is a procedure that gives as output that any statement of the theory is either true, false, or undecidable within the theory. If it is not what you want, than I don't know what it is...

Comment: The additional infos are used in constructing the proof, not in the statements that are within the original theory.

Comment: And I don't blame ZF for that, it was designed before people were aware of how hard it is to show consistency. But that doesn't mean I'm forced to accept it as consistent when it wasn't designed to make that fact (if true) clear.

Comment: given a statement, you have a method of proof to obtain its truth value. unluckily the method relies on some additional complexity that is out of the system. but it is effective in proving the statements

Comment: and for me, the very final point is the predictive power of a theory. what can you prove within it? ZFC is quite powerful; while finitary mathematics that does not include full arithmetics is not...if all your interest is in making an algorithm maybe it is sufficient, if it is predicting the behavior of very complex physical systems probably it is not.

Comment: I've said many times that what I object to is dishonesty and treating your competition unfairly. And I don't think you think either makes good science. We might be converging on a disagreement that can be resolved about ZFC+S, but hopefully we don't disagree that honesty and treating competition fairly is good in science.

Comment: obviously not; but I don't think that taking as implicit the most utilized mathematical model in physics qualifies as dishonesty. I don't see people in physics that make mathematical statements to specify which axiomatic system is sufficient to prove the claim, they simply imply they are using the most common one. If you are different, and are offended by this omission I apologize, but you got offended by almost everyone in that way I am afraid...

Comment: You say I'm "profoundly wrong" and that "In those models of $ZF+something$" but if ZF is inconsistent then there are no models of ZFC+S because inconsistent systems (like ZFC+S) have no models. Imagine that instead of ZF we used an obviously inconsistent system and then if you stop and make sure your argument isn't obviously dead in the water then you can avoid have me point out that your argument didn't convince me.

Comment: So you assume that $ZFC$ has no contradictory statements. This is an assumption for the moment. Now add an independent axiom $A$. By the hypothesis above, this is again a theory with no contradictory statements. Now if within $ZFC+A$ you can prove that $ZFC$ is non-contradictory (in fact that every statement is either true, false or undecidable) then you are confirming you starting hypothesis of non-contradictoriety. Simply you are using proofs that are "more complex" than the original system, in compliance with Gödel's theorem. Is that unconvincing?

Comment: About predictive power. There are axiom systems that are inconsistent, synthetic differential geometry is one such and it is potentially useful because it has potential predictive power because it uses a weaker deductive method to avoid generating all statements. But ZFC might generate all possible statements so the predictive power is potential zero unless you think theorems with proofs found historically earlier are better than theorems of the negations whose proofs were found later. And sure you don't like finitary methods, and that's fair non finitary methods have the advantage of a large

Comment: Obviously if the theory was inconsistent, you could not have been able to prove that everyone of its statements is either true, false or undecidable.

Comment: Large user base, and even if finitary methods were way more effective than you thought, that handicap is real.

Comment: I don't prefer finitary methods, but only because (with our knowledge) the statements I need to prove are not provable by finitary methods. And I need these statements to make interesting predictions.

Comment: "Obviously if the theory was inconsistent, you could not have been able to prove that everyone of its statements is either true, false or undecidable" if you mean for every statement you can ( prove that it is true) xor (prove that it is false) xor (prove that it is undecidable) that would not be possible if your theory were inconsistent. But that requires an infinite proofs and xor quantification over them, including saying that proofs don't exist. In skeptical in the extreme that this happens because it isn't what happens in any relative consistency proof I've seen.

Comment: And using the word true? You either need a model or should be talking about theorems and proofs and you are speaking so loosely I can't tell which you are saying.

Comment: When you prove consistency that is exactly what you prove. You define the valid statements, the axioms, the inference rules; and prove within the inference rules that any given statement $S$ satisfies ($proof(S)$+$\overline{proof{\bar{S}}}$) if true, the contrary if $S$ is false, or you prove ($\overline{proof(S)}$+$\overline{proof{\bar{S}}}$), i.e. $S$ is undecidable. If you are able to prove that for statements in a theory, using only inference rules and axioms of another theory that is the original + an independent axiom, then I don't see a problem.

Comment: Obviously this is not finitary, and you accept a possible infinite number of inferences (actually of recursive nature however) in the system. If you don't like even that, than so be it. But that is perfectly clear and formalized in logic within the inference system usually used. Many statements may be provable also by finitary, or just ciountably recursive methods (constructivism); anyways that does not mean the other method is not an acceptable alternative

Comment: Now it seems like you are saying you "prove for every statement S ..." wheareas I was saying "for every statement S you ..." If you have one proof then it is by definition finite

Comment: No the proof may have a recursive nature, since transfinite recursion is a schema of the usual logical theories. If you want to restrict recursion to just countable recursion then it is ok, but it is anyways implicitly infinite in nature.

Comment: And you keep having the word undecidable which is about provability and the word true all mixed together.

Comment: Yes, because a statement is undecidable if both $proof(S)$ and $proof(\bar{S})$ are false, i.e. there is no proof of the statement within the system. This is part of the basic Gödelization procedure in logic, i.e. seeing the proofs as (eventually) true statements of a theory

Comment: You want transfinite recursion at the level or your logic? So I guess you might want second order logic too? I'm not sure why you don't just put ZFC into your logic while you are it, if the standard is that most people do it, democracy and popularity carry real weight in mathematics. They real in science too just not as weighty.

Comment: But if you start with true and false then you started with a model. Sure if you have a model you might want some of the truths to be theorems and all theorems to be truths and similarly for falsehoods. But inconsistent systems don't have models.

Comment: Transfinite recursion is a schema in ZFC that is a first order logic; and it can be used as a tool to do proofs. Obviously however, that schema may require an infinite number of instances to be verified. And obviously you want satisfiable theories that have models (it is actually equivalent to consistency within first order logic). This is not related to the fact that consistency has to be proved outside of the system, and as I said it is actually done using additional axioms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24454/discussion-between-yuggib-and-timaeus).